# What's the difference between zlib and zlib@openssh.com?

Tags: ssh, compression

When I was debugging ssh and I found there are 2 compression method: zlib and zlib@openssh.com.

```
debug2:compression ctos: none, zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2:compression stoc: none, zlib@openssh.com,zlib
```

So is there any difference between the 2?

Answer (score 2):

In [rfc4251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251#page-4)

> There are two formats for algorithm and method names:

> Names that do not contain an at-sign ("@") are reserved to be
> assigned by IETF CONSENSUS.  Examples include "3des-cbc", "sha-1",
> "hmac-sha1", and "zlib" (the doublequotes are not part of the
> name).  Names of this format are only valid if they are first
> registered with the IANA.  Registered names MUST NOT contain an
> at-sign ("@"), comma (","), whitespace, control characters (ASCII
> codes 32 or less), or the ASCII code 127 (DEL).  Names are case-
> sensitive, and MUST NOT be longer than 64 characters.

> Anyone can define additional algorithms or methods by using names
> in the format name@domainname, e.g., "ourcipher-cbc@example.com".
> The format of the part preceding the at-sign is not specified;
> however, these names MUST be printable US-ASCII strings, and MUST
> NOT contain the comma character (","), whitespace, control
> characters (ASCII codes 32 or less), or the ASCII code 127 (DEL).
> They MUST have only a single at-sign in them.  The part following
> the at-sign MUST be a valid, fully qualified domain name [RFC1034]
> controlled by the person or organization defining the name.  Names
> are case-sensitive, and MUST NOT be longer than 64 characters.  It
> is up to each domain how it manages its local namespace.  It
> should be noted that these names resemble STD 11 [RFC0822] email
> addresses.  This is purely coincidental and has nothing to do with
> STD 11 [RFC0822].

In short, one without at-sign is a formal version and the other one is additional one made by openssh.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.openssh.com/manual.html

> OpenSSH implemented a compression method "zlib@openssh.com" that delays starting compression until after user authentication, to eliminate the risk of pre-authentication attacks against the compression code. It is described in draft-miller-secsh-compression-delayed-00.txt.

So in short it performs the same zlib compression, but starts the compression only after successful authentication, this way preventing certain type of attacks.